# Multidimensional Array and Magnitude of Gradient

Tags: python, image, numpy

I am new to python. I am trying to read an image into a multidimensional numpy array and compute the magnitude of the gradient, which should produce a single channel image. The dimensions after I compute the magnitude, however, is 700 x 900. Can anyone help me format the data, so I can receive a single channel image?

```
a = imread('20091016_tumor_26_18245948_1chop.png')
ndimage.gaussian_gradient_magnitude(a, 0.4, a)
```

Comment: The magnitude of the gradient will be computed at each pixel, hence your result is the same size as the input image.

Comment: The wiki artcile on the sobel operator may give you some more insight into what to expect: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator

Comment: But, is there any python references for computing it correctly to receive a single channel image?

Comment: I think you need to expand on your question.  Is the numpy array 2D or 3D (I assume 3D as you are reading in a .png)? Are you expecting a 2D output array?  Do you want the gradients for each channel? etc.

Comment: My numpy array is 3D and I am expecting a single channel image (scalars) from the magnitude gradient of the image

Comment: This is how I am trying to compute the magnitude of the gradient, but it doesn't work
  grad=numpy.gradient(a)
a=numpy.sqrt(grad.dot(grad))

Comment: @Carnez, Many (if not most) functions within numpy, by default, operate on each element of the array.  So, in your comment above, `gradient` gives the gradient at each pixel (which itself is a vector, so that actually _adds_ to the dimensionality).  `sqrt` and `dot` (in this case) each return an array of the same size as the input.  Please see my answer for more info.

Answer (score 2):

I think people are being confused by your terminology.  A single channel image *is* a 2D array..., a multi-channel image would be a 3D array (extra dimension to store each channel).  For example, a single channel image would be grayscale, but multi-channel would be color.  For more information, see [Channel (digital image)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel_%28digital_image%29)

If you want a scalar output, you would have to be more specific on how you want to reduce an image to a scalar.  One simple example would be the `norm` of the array, as below, but this choice should depend on your use case.

```
a = imread('20091016_tumor_26_18245948_1chop.png')  # a 2d input image
g = ndimage.gaussian_gradient_magnitude(a, 0.4)  # a 2d image showing magnitude of the gradient in a

s = np.linalg.norm(g)  # the scalar norm of the gradient
```

In your comment you suggested that you'd tried

```
grad = numpy.gradient(a)
a = numpy.sqrt(grad.dot(grad))
```

The problem here, assuming you want a scalar in the end, is that many (if not most) functions within numpy, by default, operate on each element of the array.  So, in the above code, `gradient` gives the gradient at each pixel

```
a.shape
#(H, W)
grad.shape
#(2, H, W)
```

Since the gradient itself is a vector,it actually *adds* to the dimensionality, so a 2d image becomes a 3d array.

`sqrt` and `dot` (in this case) each return an array of the same size as the input.  If you use `dot` on two arrays, it is doing the matrix version of `a.T * b`  Here, `a` and `b` are both the same shape.  The output of the inner or dot product of a 1d or 2d array has the same width as the right hand side and same height as the left hand side, hence two square matrices give a square matrix.

Here are some examples:

```
a = Image.open('kinglet_bw.jpg')
plt.imshow(a)
```

[image: a]

```
for i, g in enumerate(np.gradient(a,3,3)):
    plt.subplot(121+i)
    plt.imshow(g)
```

[image: g2]

```
g = ndimage.gaussian_gradient_magnitude(a, 3)
plt.imshow(g)
```

[image: g]

Answer (score 0):

There are two version of this approach:

The first one works:

```
from Snaxel import Snaxel
from Snake import Snake
from get_snaxels import get_snaxels;
import numpy
import scipy
from pylab import imread, imshow, gray, mean
from matplotlib.pyplot import imsave

alpha = 1.0
beta = 0.0
gamma = -10.0
delta_y = 3
delta_x = 0

row_idx = 160
contour = [];

count = 0
for i in range(0, 1000):
    contour.append((row_idx, i))


snaxels, num_snaxels = get_snaxels(contour)
a = imread('synthesized_kymogram_2.png')
f = numpy.rot90(a, 2)
f = numpy.rot90(a, 2)


snake = Snake(snaxels, alpha, beta, delta_y, delta_x, f, gamma)
snake.MinimizeEnergy()
```

But, when I revise the following to:

```
from Snaxel import Snaxel
from Snake import Snake
from get_snaxels import get_snaxels;
import numpy
import scipy
from pylab import imread, imshow, gray, mean
from matplotlib.pyplot import imsave

alpha = 1.0
beta = 0.0
gamma = -10.0
delta_y = 3
delta_x = 0

row_idx = 160
contour = [];

count = 0
for i in range(0, 1000):
    contour.append((row_idx, i))


snaxels, num_snaxels = get_snaxels(contour)
a = imread('20091016_tumor_26_18245948_1chop.png')

g=ndimage.gaussian_gradient_magnitude(a, 0.4)

snake = Snake(snaxels, alpha, beta, delta_y, delta_x, g, gamma)
snake.MinimizeEnergy()
```

I get the following error:

```
if energy < min_energy:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I thought the magnitude of the gradient would work. But, it does not? Does anyone know how to resolve it?

Comment: Hi @Carnez, you can actually edit your question (a little gray link at the bottom of your question, near the comments), and I think that would be a better place to put this information, since it's not really an answer per se.