# Discrepancy between numpy arrays in python

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to python and been have difficulty with understanding why the first snippet of code works but the other doesn't with varying images. I am interested in import an image  into a multi-dimensional numpy array. Furthermore, I have to compute the magnitude of the image gradient

f in the first code example is a ndarray while g in the second example is a ndarray

The first one works:

```
from Snaxel import Snaxel
from Snake import Snake
from get_snaxels import get_snaxels;
import numpy
import scipy
from pylab import imread, imshow, gray, mean
from matplotlib.pyplot import imsave

alpha = 1.0
beta = 0.0
gamma = -10.0
delta_y = 3
delta_x = 0

row_idx = 160
contour = [];

count = 0
for i in range(0, 1000):
    contour.append((row_idx, i))


snaxels, num_snaxels = get_snaxels(contour)
a = imread('synthesized_kymogram_2.png')
f = numpy.rot90(a, 2)
f = numpy.rot90(a, 2)


snake = Snake(snaxels, alpha, beta, delta_y, delta_x, f, gamma)
snake.MinimizeEnergy()
```

But, when I revise the following to:

```
from Snaxel import Snaxel
from Snake import Snake
from get_snaxels import get_snaxels;
import numpy
import scipy
from pylab import imread, imshow, gray, mean
from matplotlib.pyplot import imsave

alpha = 1.0
beta = 0.0
gamma = -10.0
delta_y = 3
delta_x = 0

row_idx = 160
contour = [];

count = 0
for i in range(0, 1000):
    contour.append((row_idx, i))


snaxels, num_snaxels = get_snaxels(contour)
a = imread('20091016_tumor_26_18245948_1chop.png')

g=ndimage.gaussian_gradient_magnitude(a, 0.4)

snake = Snake(snaxels, alpha, beta, delta_y, delta_x, g, gamma)
snake.MinimizeEnergy()
```

I get the following error for the second approach:

```
if energy < min_energy:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I thought the magnitude of the gradient would work. But, it does not? Does anyone know how to resolve it?

Comment: there is no such line in the posted code.

Comment: I guess my question is for a given image, the top snippet of code doesn't give me a ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() but the second snippet does?

Comment: Your example code uses two different images.  Is it possible that one of them is color and the other is greyscale, and the color one is failing?  The snake function is calculating an energy value presumably by integrating over the 2d image.  For a color image it would get 3/4 values, one per channel (RGB or RGBA).  That would result in the error you describe.

Comment: For the first image it's  (320, 1000) while the second on is (700, 900,3), which I assume is color. Do you know how I can convert to a grayscale? And, would I still need to take the gradient magnitude?

Comment: That depends on what the data actually means.  You can select a single color channel with `a = a[:,:,0]` or average all three with `a = a.mean(-1)`.  If your image is actually greyscale, just encoded as a color file, either will work.  If the color channels mean something different, you have to figure that out.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/19861135/1730674